# Возможно ли передать переменную из теста в фикстуру pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Необходимо передать в вызываемую фикстуру переменную, которая определяется в самом тесте:

```py
#содержимое conftest.py
import pytest

#в эту фикстуру нужно передать переменную x
@pytest.fixture(scope = 'function')
def case_setup():
    y = 10
    a = x / y
    yield a
```

```py
#содержимое test_test.py
class Test_Suite():

    def func1(self):
        x = 10

    #тут надо выполнить передачу
    def func2(self, case_setup):
        print(a)
```

Возможна ли такая передача переменной x? Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Все одним модулем (нет смысла делить на отдельные модули, если есть взаимозависимости):

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def case_setup():
    y = 10
    a = Test_Suite.func1() / y
    yield a


class Test_Suite():
    @staticmethod
    def func1():
        x = 10
        return x

    def test_func2(self, case_setup):
        print(case_setup)
        assert False
```

Вывод pytest:

```
user@host:~/stackoverflow$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/user/stackoverflow
collected 1 item                                                               

test_test.py F                                                           [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ Test_Suite.test_func2 _____________________________

self = <test_test.Test_Suite object at 0x7fad72b034e0>, case_setup = 1.0

    def test_func2(self, case_setup):
        print(case_setup)
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_test.py:19: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
1.0
============================== 1 failed in 0.01s ===============================
```

## Обновление:

Похоже вы хотите сделать два зависимых теста. Тогда вам нужен `pytest-dependency` (`pip install pytest-dependency`) и передача данных между тестами. Пример ниже основан на этом ответе: [Chaining tests and passing an object from one test to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244793/4752653)

```
import pytest


def pytest_namespace():
    return {'shared': None}


class Test_Suite():
    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_func1(self):
        pytest.shared = 10
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["Test_Suite::test_func1"])
    def test_func2(self):
        print(pytest.shared)
        assert False
```

Вывод pytest:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/user/stackoverflow
plugins: dependency-0.4.0
collected 2 items                                                              

test_test.py .F                                                          [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ Test_Suite.test_func2 _____________________________

self = <test_test.Test_Suite object at 0x7fe6c0174898>

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["Test_Suite::test_func1"])
    def test_func2(self):
        print(pytest.shared)
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_test.py:17: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
10
========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.04s ==========================
```

Если упадет первый тест, то второй тест будет пропущен, т.к. зависит от первого.

Comment: Спасибо, я понимал, что можно решить подобным образом, хотелось узнать - возможно ли все таки решить эту проблему, если нужно держать `test_` и `conftest` отдельно друг от друга. Так или иначе спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test_Suite():
    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_func1(self):
        pytest.shared = 10
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["Test_Suite::test_func1"])
    def test_func2(self):
        print(pytest.shared)
        assert False
```

Это всего лишь создает динамическую переменную внутри модуля pytest.
Вот так тоже будет работать.
В чем фишка то?

Comment: Интересно. Вообще похоже pytest_namespace задепрекейтили, а потом и удалили в Pytest 4.0: [Deprecations and Removals](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace). К тому же, чтобы работало через `pytest_namespace`, нужно было чтобы эта функция была прописана в отдельном модуле `conftest.py`. Получается, что и в моем ответе, и здесь это работает через просовывание инородных объектов в модуль pytest, что не есть хорошо, причем глобально для всех тестов. Я подумаю, как исправить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем нужно так Х передавать? Например так можно:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def case_setup(request):
    yield request.cls.x

class Test_Suite():
    x = 10

    def test_func1(self, case_setup):
        assert self.__class__.x == case_setup
```